# Is there a way to pass value to array Object using Promise in Node Js?

Tags: javascript, express, shopify

I am using express Js with Shopify API to get the products and save it to array. However, when I fetch all data, I check the list size and it is returned 0. I have been printing the product detail when I fetch data and no problem. Can anyone tell me what is going on? And how can I fix this problem?
here is my code:

````
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const Product = require("./Product");
const client = Client.buildClient(
  {
    domain: "storename.myshopify.com",
    storefrontAccessToken: "token",
  },
  fetch
);
const ProductList = class {
  getProductList() {
    var productList = [];
    client.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
      products.forEach((product) => {
        const p = new Product(
          product.availableForSale,
          product.createdAt,
          product.description,
          product.id,
          product.images,
          product.options,
          product.productType,
          product.publishedAt,
          product.title,
          product.variants
        );
        p.printProduct();
        productList.push(p);
      });
    });
    console.log("size:" + productList.length);
    return productList;
  }
};

module.exports = ProductList; ```
````

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your fetch and `.then` handler are running [asynchronously](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous)--so they are executing *after* you have `console.log`-ed the output and `return`ed.  You have two options:

1. You can `return` a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and `resolve` the result:

   ```js
   const fetch = require("node-fetch");
   const Product = require("./Product");
   const client = Client.buildClient({
       domain: "storename.myshopify.com",
       storefrontAccessToken: "token",
     },
     fetch
   );
   const ProductList = class {
     getProductList() {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         var productList = [];
         client.product.fetchAll().then((products) => {
           products.forEach((product) => {
             const p = new Product(
               product.availableForSale,
               product.createdAt,
               product.description,
               product.id,
               product.images,
               product.options,
               product.productType,
               product.publishedAt,
               product.title,
               product.variants
             );
             p.printProduct();
             productList.push(p);
           });
           console.log("size:" + productList.length);
           resolve(productList);
         });
       }
     }
   };

   module.exports = ProductList;
   ```
2. **OR** you can use [`async...await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) to achieve the same result:

   ```js
   const fetch = require("node-fetch");
   const Product = require("./Product");
   const client = Client.buildClient({
       domain: "storename.myshopify.com",
       storefrontAccessToken: "token",
     },
     fetch
   );
   const ProductList = class {
     async getProductList() {
       var productList = [];
       const products = await client.product.fetchAll();
       products.forEach((product) => {
         const p = new Product(
           product.availableForSale,
           product.createdAt,
           product.description,
           product.id,
           product.images,
           product.options,
           product.productType,
           product.publishedAt,
           product.title,
           product.variants
         );
         p.printProduct();
         productList.push(p);
       });
       console.log("size:" + productList.length);
       return productList;
     }
   };

   module.exports = ProductList;
   ```